# To apply border-box in all css rules

Tags: css

According to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/), we should follow this approach:

```
html {   box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after {   box-sizing: inherit; }
```

But I think that this it's more correct:

```
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Because * includes html, and pseudo-elements are preceded by ::, not : that correspond to pseudo-classes.

Am I applying properly the rule to the whole document? I don't want to use `content-box` nowhere.

Comment: So here's some comments on why `inherit` might be good https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: Kindly have a look at the Answer @CSSAsker

Comment: @jspcal yes, `inherit` it's better if you want to use in some situations `content-box`, but, if you don't want it? If you want always work with `border-box`?

Comment: The idea being that if you set it to `inherit` initially, then when you change it later at some sub-container level, then all nodes inside of it will inherit the new value.

Comment: I know @mccambridge, but if you only want to have `border-box` in the whole document? (never to use `content-box`)

Comment: @CSSAsker Then you can just go `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`. The "canonical" answers try to cover the most flexible use cases in an elegant way. If you're dead sure you are always going `border-box`, then go for the `*`. You won't see it flaunted on CSSTricks. But if it works for you, don't get beholden by convention. That said, you'll find that convention is often your friend. And if something is a convention, there's probably a good reason for it.

Answer (score 4):

Let me clear the answer,

The earliest box-sizing: border-box; reset looked like this:

```
   * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This works fairly well, but it leaves out pseudo elements, which can lead to some unexpected results. A revised reset that covers pseudo elements quickly emerged:

**Universal Box Sizing**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This method selected pseudo elements as well, improving the normalizing effect of border-box. But, the * selector makes it difficult for developers to use content-box or padding-box elsewhere in the CSS. Which brings us to the current frontrunner for best practice:

If it solve your problem , kindly Vote Up to acknowledge Community Combine time and help.
If you have any question feel free to ask.
Thank You.

Comment: [Box Sizing - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#article-header-id-3)

Comment: But if you only want to use `border-box`? And why use pseudo-class notation `:` if before and after are pseudo-elements `::`?

Comment: @CSSAsker Friend there is a fair difference b/w pseudo classes and pseudo elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements)                                                                                                                                                   And Now your question that why : Right? Because to cover both pseudo classes and pseudo elements , this problem usually happens when we use CSS Pre-Processors  , Hope you understand , if any question or problem happening feel free to post . Kind Regards Hamad.

Comment: And @CSSAsker Your Question is Great , it help me to search it's use in Pre Processors also , Thank You for posting great question.

Comment: @CSSAsker in CSS2 the **single and double colon notation** were used for pseudo-elements, in CSS3 the specification changed and only **double colon notation** should be used for pseudo-elements (but also supports **single colon notation** for backwards compatibility)

Comment: So `:` is interpreted as pseudo-class and pseudo-selector in the browsers because pre-processors, right? Thank you

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira I imagined that because the article was written in 2014, but thank you for confirm it.

Comment: @CSSAsker [this article](https://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/) will explain it better